# sklearn jaccard_score giving a wrong result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, metrics

I've used the `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score` to collect the refered score from my python model's binary classification test. It **outputs as shown** below, but when I **calculate by hand** the metric, **it yields another value**. Am I mistaken about the meaning of "jaccard" in this function's usage? Or am I using it wrong? All the other metrics collected by the sklearn functions are returning correct values.
There follows my code, with the test of jaccard by hand (doing in calculator by comparing the vectors as sets yields the same, as I'm (not so much) relieved it does).

```
def test(X, y, model):
  predictions = model.predict(X, verbose=1).ravel()
  report = classification_report(y, predictions, target_names=['nao_doentes', 'doentes'])
  confMatrix = confusion_matrix(y, predictions)
  tn, fp, fn, tp = confMatrix.ravel()
  jaccard = jaccard_score(y, predictions) # Se comportando de forma estranha

  print(tn, fp, fn, tp)
  print(predictions)
  print(y)
  print(report)
  print(confMatrix)
  print("Jaccard by function: {}".format(jaccard))
      
  # Note that in binary classification, recall of the positive class is also known as “sensitivity”;
  # recall of the negative class is “specificity”.

  dice = ((2*tp) / ((2*tp) + fp + fn))
  jaccard = ((tp + tn) / ((2*(tp + tn + fn + fp)) - (tp + tn)))
  print(dice)
  print("Jaccard by hand: {}".format(jaccard))
```

And then follows the output:

```
2 0 1 1
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1 0 1 0]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

 nao_doentes       0.67      1.00      0.80         2
     doentes       1.00      0.50      0.67         2

    accuracy                           0.75         4
   macro avg       0.83      0.75      0.73         4
weighted avg       0.83      0.75      0.73         4

[[2 0]
 [1 1]]
Jaccard by function: 0.5
0.6666666666666666
Jaccard by hand: 0.6
```

As a second issue, why `classification_report` appears to be putting `nao_doentes` (non sick, in portuguese) as 1 and `doentes` (sick) as 0? Shouldn't it be putting in the opposite way? `nao_doentes` is set as 0 and `doentes` as 1 in my sets (so in y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html), jaccard score is defined as:

> the size of the intersection divided by the size of the union of two
> label sets,

And they look only at the positive class:

> jaccard_score may be a poor metric if there are no positives for some
> samples or classes. Jaccard is undefined if there are no true or
> predicted labels, and our implementation will return a score of 0 with
> a warning.

In the confusion matrix you have, you have:

```
intersection = tp # you have 1
union = tp+fp # you have 2 
jaccard = intersection / union
```

and should give you 1 / (1+1) = 0.5 .

Your label is correct. You can convert the labels and you see that you get the same confusion matrix:

```
import pandas as pd

labels = pd.Categorical(['nao_doentes','doentes'],categories=['nao_doentes','doentes'])
prediction = [1 ,0 ,0, 0]
y = [1 ,0, 1, 0]

pd.crosstab(labels[y],labels[prediction])

col_0   nao_doentes doentes
row_0       
nao_doentes 2   0
doentes     1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

The Jaccard score calculated by hand in your question is different from the one calculated using the default scikit-learn `jaccard_score` because the equation you've used by hand is calculating the *micro-averaged* Jaccard score, whereas the scikit-learn version by default is calculating the score for the positive class ("Doentes") only.

Just to see how this is the case, we can look at how the sklearn `jaccard_score` using the default method compares to a calculation by hand:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
y_true = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0])
y_pred = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])

tp = 1
tn = 2
fp = 0
fn = 1

jaccard_score(y_true, y_pred)
#  0.5

# And we can check this by using the definition of the Jaccard score for the positive class:

tp / (tp + fp + fn)
#  0.5
```

Now let's look at the micro-averaged Jaccard score (the definition of "micro-averaged" here comes from the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html):

```
# scikit-learn:

jaccard_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
# 0.6

# Definition of micro-averaged ("Calculate metrics globally by counting 
# the total true positives, false negatives and false positives"). 
# Here we have to define another set of outcomes but this time with the 
# original negative class as the positive class:

tp_0 = 2
fp_0 = 1
tn_0 = 1
fn_0 = 0

(tp+tp_0)/(tp+tp_0+fp+fp_0+fn+fn_0)
# 0.6

# And let's now compare this to the original calculation by hand in the question:
(tp + tn) / ((2*(tp + tn + fn + fp)) - (tp + tn))
# 0.6
```